# How do I join two tables and only take values from the second table if they exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, select

TABLE1 is just 1 column & 28 rows. Each row is a DateTime for the last 28 days.

TABLE2 is 2 columns: DateTime and Value. The number of rows is unpredictable, but the DateTime will always be in the last 28 days.

I want to join these two tables, such that the resulting table has 2 columns, DateTime and Value, and 28 rows, one for each of the last 28 days. The Value column is taken from TABLE2 if present, or NULL or -1 if absent.

What is the best way to do this?

**TABLE 1** (28x1)

```
DATE
11/3/2018 12:00:00AM
11/4/2018 12:00:00AM
11/5/2018 12:00:00AM
...
...
11/30/2018 12:00:00AM
```

**TABLE 2** (4x2)

```
DATE                  | VALUE
----------------------+-------
11/3/2018 12:00:00AM  |  45
11/21/2018 12:00:00AM |  78
11/22/2018 12:00:00AM |  85
11/29/2018 12:00:00AM | 103
```

Expected result (28x2)

```
DATE                 | VALUE
---------------------+-------
11/3/2018 12:00:00AM | 45
11/4/2018 12:00:00AM | null
11/5/2018 12:00:00AM | null
...
...
11/20/2018 12:00:00AM | null
11/21/2018 12:00:00AM | 78
11/22/2018 12:00:00AM | 85
11/23/2018 12:00:00AM | null
...
11/29/2018 12:00:00AM | 103
11/30/2018 12:00:00AM | null
```

Any JOIN I've tried so far doesn't work because I must join on a column, and the only column in common is DateTime & that eliminates the rows with no values.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be great

Comment: Do you mean `45` instead of `47` in the expected results? if no, from where `47` comes?

Comment: Aside: If the `Date` column is always a date, i.e. without a meaningful time-of-day, then it should be a [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). For convenience you may want to use a column name that isn't otherwise used within SQL Server and which might convey some meaning, e.g. `BillingDate` or `EventDate`.

Comment: Are the dates in the real data set always rounded to midnight? And will table2 never have more than 1 record per day?

Comment: HABO, I've generalized the problem statement, but your point is valid.
Amir, yes and yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `left join`s were invented for:

```
SELECT    t1.[datetime], t2.[value]
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.[datetime] = t2.[datetime]
```

Comment: I tried this, and LEFT OUTER JOIN as well, but it didn't give me the expected result, only the 4 rows common to both tables.

Comment: @Freakishly this result will give you 28 rows. Some of them will have a value and the rest will be null at `value` column

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion about the column name, do not used reserved word of sqlserver in column like Date or Datetime.

Given below example that will solved your issue: (As suggested above answer you need left join)

```
declare @table1 table( dateColumn datetime)
declare @table2 table( dateColumn datetime, value int)

--insert into @table1 values ('11/3/2018 12:00:00AM' ),( '11/4/2018 12:00:00AM'), ('11/5/2018 12:00:00AM')
--To test I insert current month's all dates in @table1
Declare @year int = 2018, @month int = 11;
WITH numbers
as
(
    Select 1 as value
    UNion ALL
    Select value + 1 from numbers
    where value + 1 <= Day(EOMONTH(datefromparts(@year,@month,1)))
)

Insert into @Table1  
SELECT datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) Datum FROM numbers

insert into @table2 values ('11/3/2018 12:00:00AM' , 45), ('11/21/2018 12:00:00AM', 78), ('11/22/2018 12:00:00AM', 85), ('11/29/2018 12:00:00AM', 103)

SELECT    t1.dateColumn, t2.[value]
FROM    @table1  t1
LEFT JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.dateColumn = t2.dateColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will solve your problem.**

```
SELECT    t1.[datetime], t2.[value]
FROM      t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON cast(t1.[datetime] as date) = cast(t2.[datetime] as date)
```